# Can't get nl2br to work using PHP mailer

Tags: php, forms, mailer

I'm trying to post some information from the previous page, and then email it out.

The info that is posted from the previous page is inside a text area, and I want it to automatically add new lines when the user has pressed enter when typing in that text area.

Tried using nl2br, it doesn't seem to work. My code:

Posting from previous page:

```
$BREAKINGNEWS=nl2br($_POST['BREAKINGNEWS']);
```

Taking that info and putting it into the email's message:

```
$message .=  nl2br($BREAKINGNEWS);
```

As you can see I have put it twice, but it still doesn't work and prints out \r\n at the end of each line.

I've tried doing it just on the POST and just on the $message but it refuses to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seem that while the post happens backslash would be appeneded to ur content. can you please confirm the content is '\n' or '\\\n'.

Comment: You need to show more of your code, otherwise it's not clear what your problem is. `nl2br` works as announced.

Answer (score 1):

You might be using SQL escaping, You should only apply SQL escaping when the output is going to be used in a SQL query. Try to not escape the data when you use `nl2br()`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "\r\n" with "\n"?

```
$text = nl2br(str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $_POST['BREAKINGNEWS']));
```

**EDIT:**
Are you setting `IsHTML(true)` in PHPMailer?

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Comment: I added an edit above to my answer, have you done that? Maybe it is not liking the HTML?

Comment: I'm using HTML elsewhere in the mail which all works fine.

When I try and add that code you just posted the entire thing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$text = str_replace("\r\n", "
", $text;
```